# wine error - can't execute because its an .exe file

Tags: wine

I'm trying to run a windows executable mounted through Archive Mounter.

I followed the directions of a previous answer, which was 'Open with ISO master, change permissions of the file(s), save the .iso, mount that .iso through Archive Mounter, then execute the file through the mounted .iso'

This didnt work. I spent well around 2 hours trying to get this to work, and im at my wits end now.

Is there ANY person out there that can offer a step by step solution to get my .iso file (and the .exe files therein) to work with Wine, mounted in Archive Mounter, without giving me the same annoying "CANT EXECUTE BECAUSE ITS AN .EXE FILE' nonsense?

The file im trying to run is an autorun.exe file for a video game. Im trying to install it on wine.

The operating system is Ubuntu 10.04

Im running on 10.04 Lucid Lynx.

Comment: Why are you changing a ISO to execute a program with wine? How are you trying to run the exe file?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to provide a step by step answer if you provided a step by step explanation of what you did? It shouldn't be necessary to mark a Windows executable as executable in order to run it with wine. But many tools will assume it's a self-extracting zip-file, which will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Canonical put in an "interesting" feature in 10.04 which was intended to persuade "windows" users not to download random executables and run them.
Perhaps understandable, but flawed, since it also prevented running executable from a read-only CD/ISO.

The capability is called the "cautious launcher".

There are a few ways to workaround this - you just need to be aware of the risks.

1. Copy the executables to your desktop. Right click on the .exe file, select *Properties*, select the *Permissions* tab and check "Allow executing file as program". You should now be able to run the executable
2. mount the cd/iso and run from the terminal `wine /media/cd-name/windowsname.exe`
3. Right click on the .exe file, select *Open with other application*, followed by *Use a custom command* and use `wine` for the command.  For executables in the future - right click the exe and then select *Open with wine*.
4. remove the cautious-launcher permanently...

Edit the default launch command for wine

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/wine.desktop
```

Change from

```
Exec=cautious-launcher %f wine start /unix
```

to

```
Exec=wine start /unix %f
```

<sub>[source](http://stream-recorder.com/forum/blocked-wine-start-unix-problem-opening-exe-t6560.html)</sub>

Comment: I tried the first 3 options and it didnt disagree with me, however nothing happens. The autorun.exe program Im trying to run didnt even initalize, it started then disappeared. Any reason behind this?

Comment: Look carefully at autorun.inf - it should indicate what executable it is actually trying to run.  Run that exe.  If it doesnt work, run that exe from the terminal - it should report errors if the executable cannot be run.  Remember - not all windows applications run successfully in wine.  Consult winehq.org for compability with wine.