# Wine "untrusted source" error when attempting to run an executable

Tags: wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wine error - can't execute because its an .exe file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73650/wine-error-cant-execute-because-its-an-exe-file)

I've been trying to use the program WINE in order to download these programs on Ubuntu. On the other hand, I've gotten a message saying I cannot.

"Downloads/iTunes64Setup.exe' is not marked as executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run.  For more details, read about the executable bit."

Answer (score 1):

iTunes has some problems installing through wine, I can tell you how to get it to run, but it may not function properly, and if it does not function properly, it is a pain to remove

you would do the following, right click on the exe, go to properties, then permissions, click on allow exicution of this file, also make sure that the read and write permissions are set.  this will allow wine to open the file, and run it.